# My water pipes seem to be NPS sizes, can this be right?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

The plumbing in my new house is from the 1950s and I need to replace a section of it, a few feet of what I think is size 3/8 inch NPS. I figured this would be a simple matter, but I am completely unable to find this size pipe available in a consumer quantity.  It seems like it is only made for industrial purposes?  Where do owners of older homes find this type of pipe?

**EDIT**
Apparently my situation is odd (?) so I thought I would add some pictures.  You can see that the pipe I am replacing has OD of ~0.68" and the main pipe has OD ~0.88".  For reference you can see that a nearby 2x4 measures accurately on the calipers.

[image: pipe to replace]
[image: main pipe]
[image: 2x4 reference]

Comment: Where are you on the planet? You seem to be mixing up pipe size conventions. "DN" is metric European, "NPS" is American. Also, "s" as in 10s you reference is a pipe wall thickness designation for pipes too thin for threads. 3/8" NPS pipe being used in an American home water supply system would be **very** unusual unless used for an appliance or fixture connection of some sort. 10s does not exist at all for American home plumbing. How certain are you that it is 3/8" NPS pipe (remembering that the 3/8" is not an actual measurement you will find on the pipe itself, hence the "nominal" in NPS.

Comment: You say "schedule 40" which, to my knowledge is only used on the drain/vent (unpressurized) side of things. Odds are good you're going to have to get some flexible rubber couplings that will compress with a hose clamp to accommodate the old pipe size and transition to modern pipe sizes for your replacement pieces. If this is a pressurized supply side line, please [edit] to indicate that.

Comment: That said, if you're planning/thinking about/expecting/it's-even-a-remote-possibility-of  upgrade fixtures, you're going to run into this issue at _every_ connection, and you may want to consider doing one big upgrade of all the plumbing to modern standards in one shot instead of piecemealing it one frustrating adapter at a time.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Interesting.  I'm in the US.  I have measured it with a variety of precision calipers and the outside diameter is definitely between 0.675" and 0.685", which as far as I can tell corresponds to 3/8" NPS pipe.  Likewise, the Main pipe is ~0.87" - 0.88".  When I went searching, I only saw similar values in tables of NPS pipe. I guess this is some sort of anomaly?

Comment: @FreeMan Not a pressurized line - this is just a pipe coming off the main to a nearby sill cock, first junction after the water meter.  I'm not sure of the sch 40 part, it was a guess based on the era of the pipe, but as I can't find any pipes at the box stores with even remotely the same ODs as mine, I figured they must be NPS, which is the only standard with sizes that I could find to match mine.

Comment: @FreeMan I also added some pictures for clarification.

Comment: _Any_ supply side plumbing is pressurized - that's how the water gets from underground, up the wall and out your taps. You cannot use Schedule 40 PVC for pressurized supply lines - it's printed right there on each piece of pipe.

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE**: That clamp and wire just to the left of your thumb in your first picture is the grounding wire for your house's electrical system! If you cut metal pipe and replace it with _anything_ plastic, you are cutting your house's grounding system and creating a potentially **lethal** situation in any electrical fault. Be sure to maintain your house's grounding system, even if it means driving new grounding rods & running a new ground cable to them.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you.  As you can tell, I'm no plumber - however I have considerable experience with electricity, enough to know to keep proper grounding.  But thank you very much for the warning!  So am I correct in assuming that these aren't standard sizes any more?

Comment: @FreeMan -- Schedule 40 PVC is fine for cold water service -- pipe only suited for non-pressure service is designated DWV for Drain, Waste, Vent.  (The diameter Schedules apply to steel pipes, too...)

Comment: #TIL... I thought all the Sch 40 PVC I'd seen indicated non-pressurized. Maybe I'm imagining things...

Answer (score 5):

It's copper, so it is rigid tube, not pipe, as specified in ASTM B88 (Standard Specification for Seamless Copper Water Tube).  The actual OD is 1/8" larger than the nominal size.  So, your .88 diameter is 3/4" and your .68 diameter is a slightly fat 1/2".

Comment: TBH, the 0.68" tubing _looks_ like "black pipe" or iron pipe, but I'll absolutely yield to someone who is more sure.

Comment: It looks like all solder joints to me.  The short pup piece between the reducing tee and the valve may be leaking or leaked in the past causing some mineral deposits and corrosion of the copper.

Comment: Good point. Thought those looked like the ends of threads.

Comment: Concur - the 0.88" is spot-on for 3/4" (should be 0.875 but the caliper is limited to 2 decimal places). The 0.68" is a little high for the 0.625" that 1/2" should be, but it looks most likely that the extra 0.05" is coming from a ball of solder/corrosion, not an oddball pipe size.

Comment: Yes, the pictures make it quite clear that this is bog-standard soldered copper, and the "slightly fat" is probably from measuring on a sloppy (poorly cleaned up after soldering) solder joint on a short stub between fittings.

Comment: Copper may come as tube or as pipe ( NPS sizes).No doubt this is tube. I have a box of old brass compression fittings, some for tube size , some for pipe size; I mixed them together before I realized there were two different things.